# Gulp and elixir copy folders and minify them

Tags: javascript, laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

Currently in our `gulpfile.js` we have every single JS file being `.scripts()` 'ed.

We want to transfer from each single file, to a more logical one. Using something like a foreach loop that loops through all javascript files within a given directory, copy them to `public/js` then minify them with any plugin, and `.version()` them so they're in a build folder.

How can you foreach all those files and what would be a logical step to minify + version the files?

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate and minify, do this

```
// first arg is an array of files, relative to /resources/assets/js/ 
// second arg is the destination
mix.scripts([
  '/../bower/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
  '/myfile.js',
], 
'public/js/deps.js');
```

Although minification will only occur when you run `gulp --production`.

To version your assets, use the `elixir()` helper in your views. [It's in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir#versioning-and-cache-busting).